# Python Scrapy - Is it possible to handle that long link in Scrapy? If so why it throws that error

Tags: python, scrapy

I got this script - I extracted link using network dev tools in chrome after checking boxes for which I wanted to do the search and this is the result. I then took that link as my start_urls and wanted to get just 1 page from results as test but I'm getting Error in terminal:

```
import scrapy
from ..items import PontsItems


class Names(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ponts'

    start_urls = [
        'https://www.ponts.org/fr/annuaire/recherche?result=1&annuaire_mode=standard&annuaire_as_no=&keyword=&PersonneNom=&PersonnePrenom=&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2023&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2022&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2021&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2020&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2019&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2018&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2017&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2016&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2015&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2014&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2013&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2012&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2011&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2010', ]

    def parse(self, response):
        items = PontsItems()

        for item in response.xpath('//div[@class="single_desc"]'):
            items['name'] = item.xpath('/div[@class="single_libel"]/a/text()').get()
            items['description'] = item.xpath('/div[@class="single_details]/div/text()').get()
        yield items
```

Error is:

```
[scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET https://www.ponts.org/fr/annuaire/recherche?result=1&annuaire_mode=standard&annuaire_as_no=&keyword=&Per
sonneNom=&PersonnePrenom=&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2023&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2022&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2021&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2020&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2019&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2018&Diplom
ePromo%5B%5D=2017&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2016&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2015&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2014&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2013&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2012&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2011&DiplomePromo%5
B%5D=2010>
```

Followed by:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\adam\pycharmprojects\scrapy_things\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "c:\users\adam\pycharmprojects\scrapy_things\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\middleware.py", line 54, in process_response
    response = yield deferred_from_coro(method(request=request, response=response, spider=spider))
  File "c:\users\adam\pycharmprojects\scrapy_things\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy_proxy_pool\middlewares.py", line 287, in process_response
    ban = is_ban(request, response)
  File "c:\users\adam\pycharmprojects\scrapy_things\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy_proxy_pool\policy.py", line 15, in response_is_ban
    if self.BANNED_PATTERN.search(response.text):
  File "c:\users\adam\pycharmprojects\scrapy_things\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\response\__init__.py", line 108, in text
    raise AttributeError("Response content isn't text")
AttributeError: Response content isn't text
2020-09-15 08:12:59 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-09-15 08:12:59 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 656,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 15802,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 1.599773,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 15, 6, 12, 59, 743969),
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 15, 6, 12, 58, 144196)}
2020-09-15 08:12:59 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

I'd be greatful for clarification: Is this because Scrapy can't handle that direct link or is the site built in a way that I'd have to use some other framework? What would be solution for that specific scrape if so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you provided the exact code and log. Can't reproduce the error in my test, the response content is fetched correctly without exception.

BTW, quote is not closed in your code.

```
item.xpath('/div[@class="single_details]/div/text()').get()
```

`"` is missed in `@class="single_details`.

---

**Update**: code to extract what you want with `xpath`.

```py
import scrapy
from lxml.html import fromstring
from ..items import PontsItems


class Names(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ponts'

    start_urls = [
        'https://www.ponts.org/fr/annuaire/recherche?result=1&annuaire_mode=standard&annuaire_as_no=&keyword=&PersonneNom=&PersonnePrenom=&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2023&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2022&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2021&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2020&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2019&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2018&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2017&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2016&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2015&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2014&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2013&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2012&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2011&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2010', ]

    def parse(self, response):
        items = PontsItems()

        for item in response.xpath('//div[@class="single_desc"]'):
            name = item.xpath('./div[@class="single_libel"]/a/text()').get().strip()
            description = item.xpath('./div[@class="single_details"]').get()
            description = fromstring(description).text_content().strip()

            items['name'] = name
            items['description'] = description
        yield items
```

Comment: Hey, I commented out user_agent settings in my settings.py and it don't throw errors anymore but my items output is name:none description: none - it means I got xpath wrong or?

Comment: I tried the xpath you provided on my machine. name, description are empty. It seems you get the xpath wrong. @AdamHenry

Comment: Hey. I'm trying in shell and it returns some names but they are not matching what is shown on a page: response.xpath('//div[@class="single_desc"]/div/a/text()').get() gets me: '\n            Fatima XXXXXXXXXXX  \n   while first should be Pierre xxx...

Comment: Ok so it ignores those filters on page completely and gives first name that appear in unfiltered list. Wondering why in a script in gives None as output

Comment: for item in response.xpath('//div[@class="annuaire_result_list"]'):
            items['name'] = item.xpath('./div/div[@class="single_desc"]/div[@class="single_libel"]/a/text()').get().strip()
            items['description'] = item.xpath('./div/div[@class="single_desc"]/div[@class="single_details"]/div/text()').get().strip()
            items['year'] = item.xpath('./div/div[@class="single_desc"]/div[@class="single_details"]/div/b/text()').get().strip()
        yield items

Comment: This pulls correct data but how to got whole page? If I try to do a loop for single_desc it gives me name from outside of this page.

Comment: Answer is updated for extracting content from the page. @AdamHenry

Comment: This just extract 1 name and this name is from outside of what is filtered

Comment: putting yield items into a loop fixed it